# Background Image on pages

Tags: entities

I want to display the content of a page in the manner as present in the image below:
[image]

Are any module present for this?

Comment: Instead of searching for the module, you should do this by theming. I mean by using css.

Comment: To print like this style you need to write custom css code, to override a default theme you are used, the Idea is very easy, jUst control your block, region and give it you style ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in other answers you can do that by theming. If you want to go for modules. Then these are for you.

[Background Images](https://www.drupal.org/project/bg_image)

> Background images is a collection of modules that allows users to add background images to html elements on pages of the site

[Background Images Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/bg_image_formatter)

> This module provides an image formatter who allows you to set an image
> in background of a div. The images are from a field of an entity and
> not from a configuration page or sth else, so it's very easy to setup
> and manage.
>
> **Use cases**
>
> 1. You want to display a image on the back of a div when viewing a
>    particular node.
> 2. You want to display a random image on the back of a div on the
>    frontpage only. This can be done using Views. Create a block, select
>    the "Background Image" formatter for your image field, save, place
>    the block, boom, you're done.